# Recurring events repeatedly saves a draft every minute

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Using Outlook 2010, some of my recurring (planned, not drafts) events is saving a draft to my Drafts folder every single minute as long as it's active.

An example taken from real life is that I have a calendar entry (Appointment) occuring every day from 24-09-2012 until 28-09-2012 from 08:00 to 16:00 (GMT+1) with a blue category, only one participant (me) with subject but without a place.

So every minute from 24-09-2012 until 28-09-2012 from 08:00 to 16:00, but not from 16:00 to 08:00, a new draft is automatically saved in my Drafts folder.

**How do I get rid of that behaviour?**

Addition here: Removing the offending event just allows a new one to take its place.
There doesn't seem to be much on the sites - Microsoft calls it a "personal" issue, but there are more and more instances.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen several articles/forums that suggest this is connected to Calendar sync with some other device; frequently, Mac OS X Mountain Lion iCal is mentioned, but also iOS and other SmartPhones.

What appears to happen is the third-party calendar/device cannot accept the reminder in its current form (you might even get a warning that there is an error - e.g. invalid Attendees), and so re-saves a copy in 'Drafts' until you fix the problem. Unfortunately, this appears to re-occur, causing duplicates and Reminders that won't go away and similar.

Try disabling Sync on each of your other devices and then clear out the Reminders and Drafts. If the problem goes away, you've found the device/program/service that is causing a conflict. You can either leave sync off with that system or work with their tech support to try and troubleshoot further.

Good luck!